# Strlen not working when I put it into a function

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am trying to make a password validator that tests for the following criteria:

```
The password should be at least 8 characters long
The password should contain at least one uppercase and at least one lowercase
The password should have at least one digit
The password should 1 special character: ! @ # $ % & * : ;
```

I got the program to work WITHOUT functions, so I tried to make a function that tests each criteria but for some reason strlen will not work inside my function.  I included cstring and cctype but I can't figure out why the error persists.  Please help out!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void criteraValidation(string str1, int up, int low, int digit, int special);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 20;
    char password[SIZE];
    int Upper, Lower, Digit, SpecialChar;

    cout << "Password Validation Criteria" << endl;
    cout << "The password should be at least 8 characters long" << endl;
    cout << "The password should contain at least one uppercase and at least one lowercase letter" << endl;
    cout << "The password should have at least one digit" << endl;
    cout << "The password should 1 special character: ! @ # $ % & * : ; " << endl;

    do
    {
        Upper = Lower = Digit = SpecialChar = 0;

        cout << "Enter password: ";
        cin.getline(password, SIZE);

    }
    while (SpecialChar == 0 || Upper == 0 || Lower == 0 || Digit == 0 || strlen(password) < 8);

    cout << "All crieria have been met! Password: " << password << endl;

    return 0;
}

    void criteraValidation(string str1, int up, int low, int digit, int special)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
        {
            if (isupper(str1[i])) // checks uppercase letters
                up++;
            if (islower(str1[i])) // checks lowercase letters
                low++;
            if(isdigit(str1[i])) // checks digits
                digit++;
            if (ispunct(str1[i])) // checks special characters
                special++;
        }

        if (strlen(str1) < 8)
            cout << "Must be at least 8 characters long.\n";
        if (up == 0)
            cout << "Must be at least 1 uppercase letter.\n";
        if (low == 0)
            cout << "Must be at least 1 lowercase letter.\n";
        if (digit == 0)
            cout << "Must have at least 1 digit.\n";
        if (special == 0)
            cout << "Must have 1 special character" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Rather use `str1.length()`. Or if you must, you could do `strlen(str1.c_str())`.

Comment: Where is your call to `criteraValidation`? So far it looks like you have infinite do/while loop and nothing else.

Comment: Don’t use char arrays. Make password a std::string. Use a range based for loop: `for(char c: str1) { if( isupper(c)...`.

Comment: If a function should change a parameter you have to use a reference.

Comment: In your `do-while` loop, you should remove `Upper, Lower, Digit, SpecialChar` from the content and the `while` expression.  Their values don't change.

Comment: Also, the `strlen` function requires a pointer to a character, not a `std::string`.  Use either `str1.length()` or `strlen(str1.c_str())`.

Comment: I recommend removing the parameters `up, low, digit, special` from the parameters of the `criteraValidation` function.  Make them local variables and initialize them to 0.  They are not used outside of this function.

Comment: Your `criteraValidation` function should return some kind of status to the caller. Otherwise the caller has no idea if the password is valid or not (and continues executing for invalid passwords).

Comment: BTW, your `main` function doesn't call `criteraValidation` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you may want something like this:

```
void criteraValidation(const string& str1, // Pass by const reference since it won't be modified.  
                       int& up, int& low, int& digit, int& special);  

    void criteraValidation(const string& str1,
                          int& up, int& low, int& digit, int& special)
    {
        up = 0;
        low = 0;
        digit = 0;
        special = 0;
        const std::string::size_type length = str1.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(str1[i])) // checks uppercase letters
                up++;
            if (islower(str1[i])) // checks lowercase letters
                low++;
            if(isdigit(str1[i])) // checks digits
                digit++;
            if (ispunct(str1[i])) // checks special characters
                special++;
        }

        if (str1.length() < 8)
            cout << "Must be at least 8 characters long.\n";
        if (up == 0)
            cout << "Must be at least 1 uppercase letter.\n";
        if (low == 0)
            cout << "Must be at least 1 lowercase letter.\n";
        if (digit == 0)
            cout << "Must have at least 1 digit.\n";
        if (special == 0)
            cout << "Must have 1 special character" << endl;
    }
```

In main:

```
do
{
    Upper = Lower = Digit = SpecialChar = 0;

    cout << "Enter password: ";
    cin.getline(password, SIZE);
    criteraValidation(password, Upper, Lower, Digit, SpecialChar);
}
while (SpecialChar == 0
       || Upper == 0
       || Lower == 0
       || Digit == 0
       || (password.length() < 8));
```

*Note:  The `isupper`, `islower`, `isdigit` and `ispunct` are exclusive (a character can't be both upper and lower case), so you may want to use an `if-else-if` ladder so that not all comparisons are always executed:*

```
const char c = str1[i];
if (isupper(c))
{
   ++up;
}
else if (islower(c))
{
   ++low;
}
else if (isdigit(c))
{
   ++digit;
}
else if (ispunct(c))
{
   ++special;
}
else
{
  // Put code here for characters not of above types.
}
```

For example, for the character 'A' only one function is executed, whereas all the comparisons are executed in your code.

Answer (score -1):

your example shows strlen() working on an array of char. When you pass it to a function you're sending in a 'string'. Is that a std::string? do you need to call strlen(str1.c_str())?